# How to preserve id's after data balancing technique like ROSE, SMOTE

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, resampling

```
df1 = data.frame(id=c('A1','2','B3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'),s1c1=c(0,0.2,0,0.5,0.8,0,0,0,0,0),s1c2=c(0,0,0.3,0,0,0.9,0.3,0,0,0),s1c3=c(0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.2,0.8,0.1))
df2 = data.frame(id=c('A1','2','B3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'),s2c1=c(0,0.22,0,0.35,0.8,0,0,0,0,0),s2c2=c(0,0,0.23,0,0,0.7,0.3,0,0,0),s2c3=c(0.2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.4,0.9,0.4))
df <- merge(df1,df2, by="id",all=TRUE)
df$class <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0) 
> df
  id s1c1 s1c2 s1c3 s2c1 s2c2 s2c3 class
  10  0.0  0.0  0.1 0.00 0.00  0.4     0
   2  0.2  0.0  0.0 0.22 0.00  0.0     0
   4  0.5  0.0  0.0 0.35 0.00  0.0     0
   5  0.8  0.0  0.0 0.80 0.00  0.0     0
   6  0.0  0.9  0.0 0.00 0.70  0.0     0
   7  0.0  0.3  0.0 0.00 0.30  0.0     1
   8  0.0  0.0  0.2 0.00 0.00  0.4     1
   9  0.0  0.0  0.8 0.00 0.00  0.9     0
  A1  0.0  0.0  0.1 0.00 0.00  0.2     0
  B3  0.0  0.3  0.0 0.00 0.23  0.0     0
```

I am using ROSE function to generate samples for imbalanced data. But, I want to preserve the id's for each observation from df after ROSE. I am getting below output after using ROSE.

```
 df.rose <- ROSE(class ~ ., data=df, seed=123,N=20,p=0.25)$data

> df.rose
 id        s1c1         s1c2          s1c3        s2c1         s2c2        s2c3   class
 B3 -0.24636399  0.513435064 -0.0844105623  0.04695640  0.419960189  0.08112992     0
  9 -0.05029030  0.199689698  0.7022285344  0.08255245 -0.133951228  1.16820765     0
  9 -0.23671562  0.167377715  0.9634146745 -0.10923003 -0.129948534  1.00641398     0
 B3 -0.16816685  0.434632663 -0.0174671002 -0.07245581  0.423706144 -0.07969934     0
  9 -0.14420654 -0.015047974  0.8530741203 -0.22148879 -0.053786877  1.18091542     0
  9 -0.38914709 -0.074365870  0.7940190162 -0.23306056 -0.230564666  1.14293933     0
  6  0.19329086  0.807524478 -0.0089820194  0.06600218  0.734243934  0.13409831     0
  6  0.03538563  0.731147735  0.2867432037  0.09746303  0.673766711  0.05837655     0
  4  0.23741363 -0.050535412 -0.0473024899  0.36152575  0.001088718 -0.15354050     0
  2  0.48927513 -0.307561385  0.3177238885  0.42054668  0.072770343  0.33271737     0
 B3  0.09839211  0.827176406 -0.3244875053  0.44579006  0.159991098 -0.14678016     0
 B3 -0.06807770  0.593601657  0.1224855617 -0.10677452  0.351707470  0.53486376     0
  9  0.20651979 -0.272977578  0.8259493668 -0.50212781 -0.041644690  1.27476593     0
  8  0.00000000 -0.008315345  0.0008152742  0.00000000  0.043469230  0.29596908     1
  7  0.00000000  0.155050387 -0.0068404803  0.00000000  0.314397160 -0.50556877     1
  7  0.00000000 -0.008021610  0.0639465277  0.00000000  0.122372337  0.27856790     1
  8  0.00000000 -0.070217063  0.2370763279  0.00000000 -0.013168583  0.04034823     1
  7  0.00000000  0.469712631  0.0130102656  0.00000000  0.566767608  0.18219645     1
  7  0.00000000  0.193749720 -0.0788801623  0.00000000  0.383380004  0.47007644     1
  7  0.00000000  0.412273782 -0.1046108759  0.00000000  0.307614552 -0.35552820     1
```

I am not getting all id's after ROSE. I want to get my all the id's. If any one know any other method to handle imbalance data by preserving id for each observation. I don't want to messed up id's. I have tried oversampling, undersampling, SMOTE. But, no good results. I have tried converting id column to factor but didn't work.

Comment: What are you expecting as output? In oversampling, more samples will be generated , so what would be the ids of those samples?

Comment: I want all those original id's. It is ok if it creates duplicate id's but i want all of them in my resample data

Comment: For eg. In my original set I have row with id 5 but in resampled data row with id 5 is missing.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still wondering, I ended up using this method. I wanted only the new synthetic observations, but SMOTE kept reducing the size of my dataset. Hope it helps:

```
library(DMwR)
library(dplyr)

# df - dataframe you want to use over/undersampling on

df$ID <- seq.int(nrow(df))
df_smote <- DMwR::SMOTE(var ~ ., df, perc.over = 100, k = 5)
sub_df <- subset(df_smote, var == "yes")
final_df <- rbind(df, sub_df)
final_df <- distinct(final_df)
```

> 1. Create ID column so it will ensure that rows are exactly the same (not
>    an observation with same set of features)
> 2. Use SMOTE with desired parameters (where *var* is the binary variable
>    on which you have imbalance).
> 3. Subset the synthetic observations with *var* of certain level - in
>    this case "yes" level.
> 4. Row bind subset to the original dataset.
> 5. Remove duplicates introduced in SMOTE.
> 6. And you end up with original dataset with only synthetic observations
>    with desired level over/undersampled.